# How to get shipping origin address for a Bigcommerce store through API

Tags: bigcommerce

How to get the shipping origin of a BigCommerce store through the APIs available. I was able to retrieve the store information address but that differs from the shipping origin address I have configured for my development store

Answer (score 0):

It's not documented, however you can use `/stores/{{store_hash}}/v3/store/locations?is_default_shipping_origin=true` to get this info.

Comment: this returns 404